# Fix JSON dict without double-quotes

Tags: python, json, double-quotes

I have a list of JSON dict that is not in valid JSON format.
They are all listed in a text file

```
"{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 30, 'tasks' [1, 2, 3], 'description': 'writer'}"
"{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 33, 'tasks' [4, 5, 6], 'description': 'runner'}"
"{'name': 'Kelly', 'age': 23, 'tasks' [7, 8, 9], 'description': 'singer'}"
```

what I would like to have is

```
 {"name": "Alice", "age": 30, "tasks" [1, 2, 3], "description": "writer"}
 {"name": "Bob", "age": 33, "tasks" [4, 5, 6], "description": "runner"}
 {"name": "Kelly", "age": 23, "tasks" [7, 8, 9], "description": "singer"}
```

to have a valid JSON

Comment: You fix this type of problem by working out how the file was created and changing that to output `json` instead of what it is doing now.

Comment: @quamrana, in my Python code, I have a for loop that generates flattened JSON files. These JSON files are recursively appended to a file (for example a .csv file) using the same for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I use replaceAll() for this purpose

```
let obj = [
"{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 30, 'tasks' [1, 2, 3], 'description': 'writer'}",
"{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 33, 'tasks' [4, 5, 6], 'description': 'runner'}",
"{'name': 'Kelly', 'age': 23, 'tasks' [7, 8, 9], 'description': 'singer'}"
]

let jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).replaceAll("\'","\""))
```

Comment: What if the JSON list is saved within a .csv file?

Answer (score 1):

i think the code like this

```
import json

data = [
    "{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 30, 'tasks': [1, 2, 3], 'description': 'writer'}",
    "{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 33, 'tasks': [4, 5, 6], 'description': 'runner'}",
    "{'name': 'Kelly', 'age': 23, 'tasks': [7, 8, 9], 'description': 'singer'}"
]

def fix_json(json_str):
    json_str = json_str.strip().replace("'", '"')  # Replace single quotes with double quotes
    json_str = json_str.replace('"tasks" [', '"tasks": [')  # Add colon after "tasks"
    return json_str

# Fix the JSON format of each JSON string
fixed_data = [fix_json(json_str) for json_str in data]

# Convert the fixed JSON strings into a valid JSON array
json_array = '[' + ','.join(fixed_data) + ']'

# Load the JSON array
result = json.loads(json_array)

# Print the valid JSON
print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

[image: images]

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to replace the **"** (opening double quotes) with **{** and **"** (closing double quotes) with **}** and then use replace to replace all the single quotes with double quotes and then use `json.dumps(some_str)` to convert it to JSON string. and you can append it to a new list or use it as you like.

```
import re, json
data = ["{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 30, 'tasks': [1, 2, 3], 'description':'writer'}",
"{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 33, 'tasks': [4, 5, 6], 'description': 'runner'}",
"{'name': 'Kelly', 'age': 23, 'tasks': [7, 8, 9], 'description': 'singer'}"]
new_data = []
for n in data:
    n = re.sub('^".+','{',n)
    n = re.sub('$"."','}',n) 
    n = n.replace("'",'"')
    n = json.dumps(n)
    new_data.append(n)
```